# Create Vertical-Tabbed OS X Cocoa View

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, user-interface, tabbed

I'm interested in having a application with a layout similar to the tabbed operation of iChat (see image below).

[image: iChat]

Does anyone know of any pre-built constructs that allow this sort of UI? I know there is NSTabView for tabs across the top of the application, but what about vertical orientation? For my purposes, the view associated with the tabs doesn't necessarily need to scroll. In fact it has nothing to do with chatting anyway, I simply like this layout.

Thanks.

Comment: The image is broken it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view on the left is an `NSTableView` with source list-style highlighting:

```
tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList;
```

You can use a tabless `NSTabView` for the right part, but you could just as well change the content of the displayed views or swap the views entirely. That depends on how many “tabs” there’ll be and how the content displayed on the right side will be different.